# How to make custom CSS have priority over CSS defined in head.phtml in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, css

I'm sure many of you come across this issue: in some third party themes, many predefined styles and css generated from theme configuration (located in pub/media/{theme}) are loaded in

`/{vender}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/template/html/head.phtml`

which have priority over your custom theme that is usually defined in

`/{vender}/{child_theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

because the css files in head.phtml always loads after the custom css.

The theme I'm using is Smartwave_porto, so far I can only resolve it by removing the css files from head.pthml, then use symlinks to create the same files and load them in default_head_blocks.xml together with my custom css. I wonder if there's better solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `media="all"` attribute in css declaration, with this Magento add it in the last of css files.

Why last ? because a property that redefined in the last CSS file, it will override the previous property statements one.

> app/design/frontend/{Vender}/{child_theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<head>
    <css src="css/custom.css" media="all"/>
</head>
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work. It seems the css defined in head.phtml always have priority over the css defined in default_head_blocks.xml. Regardless of using media="all" or not. I'm on Magento 2.3 btw.

Comment: When you inspect the source code of your page, you see the custom css loaded last ?